# Google apps script how to delete a trigger from another project

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

How do I obtain the triggers for another document in my account?
There are two functions to obtain a list of triggers:

1. ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
2. ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(document|form|spreadsheet)

The first returns only the triggers for the current project (as expected), but the second is always returning an empty array, except when called from the project where the trigger resides.

Comment: Curious, I get the same result, but only for other documents. It works fine for the current doc. I've never actually had to use that, so it's not clear to me if it's intended that you can only get it for the current script, and not scripts for other docs (I have a feeling it might be). Lets wait and see if anyone else knows and if not we can list it at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list and see what Google say.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in the ScriptApp.getUserTriggers() function (or its documentation).

What is happening is not that empty arrays are always returned. Rather, the getUserTriggers() function is returning the triggers associated with the calling script, rather than the script bound to the specified document|spreadsheet|form. If the calling script has no triggers, getUserTriggers() will return an empty array.

The issue has been taken up by the Apps Script team. In the meantime, it is not possible to programmatically view or manipulate triggers of a script from another script.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but I've listed this issue on the script issues page at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4562&thanks=4562&ts=1416775997, as no-one seems to know the answer, so we'll need to wait for the Google team to clarify.

Please star it so that it gains visibility and traction.

Edit: As per Ryans mention below, the issue I listed has been picked up the the Apps script team (Based on the owner being 'ryanr...@google.com', I suspect it's Ryan himself who has picked it up, Thanks Ryan!). So currently the only solution is to wait for a fix I believe.